# opnestack instance build failed due to allocation of networks failed

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

While creating instance on a ubuntu based openstack computes , instance build is failing on all computes with reason either 1. failed to allocate networks 2. vif creation failed.

below error messages are observed in neutron openvswitch agent log. These errors are suppressed when vif_plugging_is_fatal=false and vif_plugging_timeout=0 is set, but network connections are not problem after vm is up.

```
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1022:2020-04-08 05:55:18.823 718487 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.async_process [-] Error received from [ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Bridge name --format=json]: ovsdb-client: tcp:127.0.0.1:6640: Open_vSwitch database was removed
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1023:2020-04-08 05:55:18.823 718487 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.async_process [-] Process [ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Bridge name --format=json] dies due to the error: ovsdb-client: tcp:127.0.0.1:6640: Open_vSwitch database was removed
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1024:2020-04-08 05:55:18.856 718487 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.async_process [-] Error received from [ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Interface name,ofport,external_ids --format=json]: ovsdb-client: tcp:127.0.0.1:6640: Open_vSwitch database was removed
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1025:2020-04-08 05:55:18.857 718487 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.async_process [-] Process [ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Interface name,ofport,external_ids --format=json] dies due to the error: ovsdb-client: tcp:127.0.0.1:6640: Open_vSwitch database was removed
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1027:2020-04-08 05:55:26.991 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ofswitch [req-b7b1e5eb-5ce0-45b3-97e3-c3e1fca161ee - - - - -] ofctl request version=0x4,msg_type=0x12,msg_len=0x38,xid=0x194bc860,OFPFlowStatsRequest(cookie=0,cookie_mask=0,flags=0,match=OFPMatch(oxm_fields={}),out_group=4294967295,out_port=4294967295,table_id=23,type=1) timed out: Timeout: 10 seconds
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1028:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int [req-b7b1e5eb-5ce0-45b3-97e3-c3e1fca161ee - - - - -] Failed to communicate with the switch: RuntimeError: ofctl request version=0x4,msg_type=0x12,msg_len=0x38,xid=0x194bc860,OFPFlowStatsRequest(cookie=0,cookie_mask=0,flags=0,match=OFPMatch(oxm_fields={}),out_group=4294967295,out_port=4294967295,table_id=23,type=1) timed out
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1029:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int Traceback (most recent call last):
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1030:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/openflow/native/br_int.py", line 52, in check_canary_table
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1031:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int     flows = self.dump_flows(constants.CANARY_TABLE)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1032:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/openflow/native/ofswitch.py", line 162, in dump_flows
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1033:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int     reply_multi=True)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1034:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/openflow/native/ofswitch.py", line 110, in _send_msg
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1035:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int     raise RuntimeError(m)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1036:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int RuntimeError: ofctl request version=0x4,msg_type=0x12,msg_len=0x38,xid=0x194bc860,OFPFlowStatsRequest(cookie=0,cookie_mask=0,flags=0,match=OFPMatch(oxm_fields={}),out_group=4294967295,out_port=4294967295,table_id=23,type=1) timed out
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1037:2020-04-08 05:55:26.992 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.br_int 
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1044:2020-04-08 05:55:34.564 718487 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.async_process [-] Error received from [ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Interface name,ofport,external_ids --format=json]: 2020-04-08T05:55:34Z|00001|fatal_signal|WARN|terminating with signal 15 (Terminated)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1045:2020-04-08 05:55:34.564 718487 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.async_process [-] Process [ovsdb-client monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:6640 Interface name,ofport,external_ids --format=json] dies due to the error: 2020-04-08T05:55:34Z|00001|fatal_signal|WARN|terminating with signal 15 (Terminated)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1047:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp [req-b7b1e5eb-5ce0-45b3-97e3-c3e1fca161ee - - - - -] Agent main thread died of an exception: AsyncProcessException: Process is not running.
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1048:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp Traceback (most recent call last):
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1049:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/openflow/native/ovs_ryuapp.py", line 40, in agent_main_wrapper
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1050:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp     ovs_agent.main(bridge_classes)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1051:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/ovs_neutron_agent.py", line 2305, in main
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1052:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp     agent.daemon_loop()
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1053:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 158, in wrapper
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1054:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp     result = f(*args, **kwargs)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1055:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/ovs_neutron_agent.py", line 2213, in daemon_loop
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1056:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp     self.rpc_loop(polling_manager=pm, bridges_monitor=bm)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1057:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1058:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp     self.gen.next()
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1059:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ovsdb_monitor.py", line 50, in get_bridges_monitor
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1060:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp     mon.stop()
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1061:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/agent/linux/async_process.py", line 133, in stop
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1062:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp     raise AsyncProcessException(_('Process is not running.'))
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1063:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp AsyncProcessException: Process is not running.
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1064:2020-04-08 05:55:34.996 718487 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.openflow.native.ovs_ryuapp 
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1065:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 CRITICAL neutron [-] Unhandled error: AsyncProcessException: Process is not running.
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1066:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron Traceback (most recent call last):
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1067:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/bin/neutron-openvswitch-agent", line 10, in <module>
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1068:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     sys.exit(main())
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1069:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/cmd/eventlet/plugins/ovs_neutron_agent.py", line 20, in main
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1070:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     agent_main.main()
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1071:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/main.py", line 47, in main
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1072:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     mod.main()
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1073:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/openflow/native/main.py", line 35, in main
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1074:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     'neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.'
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1075:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/base/app_manager.py", line 375, in run_apps
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1076:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     hub.joinall(services)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1077:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 102, in joinall
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1078:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     t.wait()
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1079:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 175, in wait
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1080:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     return self._exit_event.wait()
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1081:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 125, in wait
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1082:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     current.throw(*self._exc)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1083:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 214, in main
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1084:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     result = function(*args, **kwargs)
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1085:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 64, in _launch
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1086:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron     raise e
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1087:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron AsyncProcessException: Process is not running.
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1088:2020-04-08 05:55:35.001 718487 ERROR neutron 
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1107:2020-04-08 05:56:38.606 1119073 ERROR neutron.services.trunk.drivers.openvswitch.agent.ovsdb_handler [-] No port present on trunk bridge tbr-8f8a25d8-8 in 60 seconds.: WaitTimeout: Timed out after 60 seconds
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1108:2020-04-08 05:56:38.608 1119073 ERROR neutron.services.trunk.drivers.openvswitch.agent.ovsdb_handler [-] No port present on trunk bridge tbr-04eb6917-6 in 60 seconds.: WaitTimeout: Timed out after 60 seconds
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1109:2020-04-08 05:56:38.608 1119073 ERROR neutron.services.trunk.drivers.openvswitch.agent.ovsdb_handler [-] No port present on trunk bridge tbr-75f9f38b-3 in 60 seconds.: WaitTimeout: Timed out after 60 seconds
neutron-openvswitch-agent.log.1:1110:2020-04-08 05:56:38.609 1119073 ERROR neutron.services.trunk.drivers.openvswitch.agent.ovsdb_handler [-] No port present on trunk bridge tbr-53dbeb8d-2 in 60 seconds.: WaitTimeout: Timed out after 60 seconds
```

any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did u try restarting the network-related services, try it, also check whether you have enough network resources like IP during the VM creation?

Comment: I have restarted network services on both controller and computes. the problem only appearing when I'm deploying VM with trunk port configuration. Normal deployment is working fine. no problems observed.